# JQuery Ajax function called twice with same data

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I'm building a very simple page that is a to-do list. It accepts input from a user via a form for new to-dos, POSTs the to-do to the server, then receives (almost) the same data back and adds it to a list. However, every time data is supposed to be sent to the server, the $.ajax function is called twice.

My js:

```
// todo.js
function onload() {
 $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
 $( "#todoform" ).submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  sendtodo();
  return false;
 });
}
function sendtodo() {
 $.ajax({
  url: '/blog/todo/newtodo/',
  type: "POST",
  success: function(data) {
   receivetodo(data);
  },
  data: ({
   body: $('#newbodytextarea').val(),
   title: $('#titleinput').val(),
   dateDue: $('#datepicker').val(),
   time: $('#timepicker').val(),
   category: $('#newcategory').val()}),
});
}
function receivetodo(data) {
 $('#todobody').append(data);
}
```

And part of my HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Todo list</title>
<link href="/django_media/css/todo/todo.style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/django_media/css/jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/django_media/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/django_media/js/jquery-ui-custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/django_media/js/todo/todo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  onload();
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
[.................]
</body>
</html>
```

In case it matters, I am using Django for my back-end. The data that is being returned is a `<div>` containing a couple other `<div>` tags and some `<h1>` and `<p>` tags. The part of the code that appends the received HTML to the page works fine except that it appends it twice (and the data really is in the database twice).

I've tried using `$("#todoform").click(function(e){` instead of `$("#todoform").submit(function(e){` but that didn't change anything. I also made sure `onload()` is only being called once. Why is `sendtodo()` executing twice?

If you need any other code I can post it as well.

Comment: have you checked $('#todoform').data('events').submit in the firebug console to see if it has been bound twice?

Comment: It does look like it has been bound twice. Is there a particular function I can use to clear all event handlers before I bind the handler?

Comment: You can use `.unbind('submit')` for this

Comment: @Yi that did it. If you or @lain creates an answer I will accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Replace this:

```
$( "#todoform" ).submit(function(e)
```

With this:

```
$( "#todoform" ).unbind('submit').submit(function(e)
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably `onload()` is being called twice, check all occurrences of it through your code. If you call `.submit()` twice, the onsubmit event is appended with the code given, not replaced.

To debug, put an `alert('anything')` inside `sendtodo()` and check if it's really being called  twice when submitting.

You can also do:

```
$('#todoform').removeAttr('onsubmit').submit( ...
```

But it would be better to find out why it's being bound twice

Comment: `sendtodo()` is being called twice when I submit the form. Firebug is showing the same listener is bound to my form twice.